# What are the limitations of the free version of FRAPS?

Tags: fraps

I know there is a [downloadable version of FRAPS](http://www.fraps.com/download.php) for free. However, I don't know what kind of limitations this version has.

Neither the [download page](http://www.fraps.com/download.php) nor the [support (FAQ) page](http://www.fraps.com/faq.php) describe the limitations. The ["buy" page](http://www.fraps.com/buy.php) only lists these as the full version advantages:

- Record as long as you like.
- Perform full-size recording with no watermarks on your movie.
- Capture screenshots directly to JPG, PNG and TGA formats!

But I have a feeling this is not the whole story. What are the actual limitations of the free version of FRAPS? Is it time-limited? Are there nagging screens? Is there a watermark while playing the game? Is there any feature that is not available in this version? Is there anything else I haven't mentioned?

Comment: This is a question about software, not games. The most important limitations, if I remember correctly, are: 1 minute max, `www.fraps.com` at the top of the video.

Comment: If so, let's move it to SuperUser

Comment: This question is fine here.

Comment: @badp, I share the same opinion. FRAPS is a game-related tool, aimed at gamers. For me, it makes perfect sense to ask here.

Comment: If questions about Steam are on topic, questions about FRAPS are on topic. Just don't take it [too far](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1402/video-conversion-question)

Comment: @StrixVaria that's a false parallel; Steam is *only* for games, FRAPS has other non-gaming uses and is not itself a game.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The free version of FRAPS has a thirty second recording limit, and embeds a watermark at the top of the recorded video. (You may have seen Youtube videos of games with "www.fraps.com" at the top in white text, which are thirty seconds long or less - this is why). Additionally, when saving screenshots, it can only do so in BMP format.

These are the only limitations on the free version. It doesn't place a watermark during gameplay, only on the recorded video. All other features are functional.