# Where does MSI Afterburner store mic audio?

Tags: recording

I recorded some gameplay with MSI afterburner, and I got the video clip, and game audio, but no mic audio. I purposefully unchecked the feature that mixes in mic audio as it mutes the game audio and just sounds bad whenever I talk. I planned to add in the mic audio later in After Effects, but alas I can't even find the file. I expected it to be with the video clip, but nope. And it can't be a push to talk issue, as both push to record buttons for mic and game audio are set to none, and the game audio still came through. Any ideas?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about graphics card software.  We have determined that graphics cards are not gaming-specific hardware, therefore general support regarding them does not happen here.  You may get some help at SuperUser, but be sure to read their FAQ first.

Comment: Try opening the software, finding a "Settings" area, and looking for a "Save Location" field.  Your previous recording should be located around there.

Comment: I did, and I couldn't find any. The only save location is for the video, sadly.

Comment: I disagree with this being off-topic, since questions about Fraps (http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/34249/what-are-the-limitations-of-the-free-version-of-fraps) seem to be allowed. While MSI Afterburner does have features specific to graphics card settings, it also is a very good free screen recorder, which is exactly the use case that OP is asking about.

Comment: I figured it out! Afterburner stores the mic audio as a separate track within the clip, opening it in VLC let me switch the audio track easily. So now it's just a matter of merging the tracks with another program.

Comment: @Frank I should have tagged you in my first comment, but can you make it clear why the question about Fraps that I linked is valid and this one isn't?